# How to join these tables safely?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `Table1`. My application code reads from `Table1` like this:

`Select id, table2_id, table3_id from Table1`

I would like it to also return values `name` from tables `Table2` and `Table3` by changing my query like this:

```
select t1.id, t1.table2_id, t1.table3_id, t2.name, t3.name
from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.table2_id = t2.id
left outer join table3 t3 on t1.table3_id = t3.id
```

However, I don't want to change the behavior of the original query, which returns 1 result per row in `Table1`.

I believe my changes to the query are safe because they `t2.id` and `t3.id` are unique columns, so `Table2` and `Table3` will contain at most 1 record for each `Table3` record. If I was to user `inner join`, this changes would not be safe, because my query would return no results if `Table2` or `Table3` happen to not contain the expected record.

For this scenario, are my changes safe and correct? Or is it necessary to write some subqueries to join on?

Comment: The left join  return the rows  for table1 also when there is not match in table2 or table3  ..  .. your query is correct   ..but what do you mean with "safe" .. ??

Comment: @scaisEdge i mean consistent with the behavior of the previous query. specifically, the query should return exactly 1 result for each row in `Table1`

Comment: The result should be consistent  .. but be sure that the t2.id and t3.id not only are unique columns but have also just one rows otherwise the query return as many rows  as the number of rows that match for each id ..

Comment: how can they have more than one row if the columns are unique?

Comment: You mean you have a unique constraints  on these columns  ?

Comment: @scaisEdge yes. the id column is unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks safe:

```
select t1.id, t1.table2_id, t1.table3_id, t2.name, t3.name
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2 
     on t1.table2_id = t2.id left join
     table3 t3
     on t1.table3_id = t3.id;
```

You can also phrase this using correlated subqueries (or a lateral join):

```
select t1.*,
       (select t2.name from table2 t2 where t1.table2_id = t2.id) as t2_name,
       (select t2.name from table3 t3 where t1.table2_id = t3.id) as t3_name,
from table1 t1;
```

This is even more of a guarantee that there are no duplicates.  If there were, the query would return an error.

Comment: thanks, could you clarify how the correlated subquery approach avoids issues with duplicates? i would think issues may occur if there was more than 1 record in `table2` for which `table2.id = table1.table2_id` (how would the database know which `name` to return?). i think the error you described is intended for this scenario, that if this were to happen the database will give an error rather than a result? is this error behavior specific to postgres? (i feel like mysql handles these situations differently?)

Comment: @ab11 . . . These are *scalar* subqueries.  If they return more than one row, then the data engine will report an error.